# How to call cloud workflows(gcp) sequentially?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-workflows

how to call cloud workflows sequentially?
I don't want to start workflow when another (same) workflow is processing.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options:

1. create a primary top level worklow that calls all the other workflows using the [googleapis.workflowexecutions.v1.projects.locations.workflows.executions.create](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/executions/rest/v1/projects.locations.workflows.executions/create) action as steps

literally this means you have 1 main workflow with many steps, each trigger one workflow after the other using the above `call` statement. Steps are executed sequentially.

2. Leverage [Firestore API](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/firestore/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument) to write a flag to a collection that controls whether a workflow is in progress, and if another workflow starts check the flag and stop.

Comment: Thank you, but workflows is called by another system.
I choose only 2.
Do you have other way only use cloud workflows?